# Vertical scrolling every 5 second

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to create vertical scrolling animation.

I have 9 elements in div with overflow hidden and height that you can see only 3 at the time.

Every 5 second I just want to add them style with minus `margin-top` and change `orderStep` variable. So if orderStep is equal to 1 then I add to all elements margin 0 when it's 1 I add `margin-top: -190px;` and when it's 2 i add -380px.

I have function which is doing this in `methods` object and I execute it on `created` after getting records from backend.

Unfortunetally it doesn't work, my code is:

```
     data() {
         return {
             articles: [],
             errors: [],
             step: 1
         }
     },
     methods: {
        changeSlide() {
            const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.most__popular');
            setInterval(() => {
                switch (this.step) {
                    case 1:
                        for(let val of elements) {
                            val.style.margin = "10px 0";
                        }
                        this.step = 2;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for(let val of elements) {
                            val.style.margin = "-190px 0 0 0";
                        }
                        this.step = 3;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for(let val of elements) {
                            val.style.margin = "-380px 0 0 0";
                        }
                        this.step = 1;
                        break;
                }
            },5000);
        }
    },
    async created() {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`/api/article/getMostPopular.php`, axiosConfig);
            this.articles = response.data.records;
            this.changeSlide();
        } catch (e) {
            this.errors.push(e)
        }
    },
```

It doesn't change style of my elements at all. In firefox console I don't have any errors.

My init value for step variable is 1 as you can see in `data()` ( i added it in edit ).

---

**EDIT**

I've done some more debugging and I found out that `document.querySelectorAll` is not giving me correct NodeList, it's empty. That's probably because I'm refering to elements which is rendered with `v-for` from async backend call (`response` from `created()`) but I thought that I can refer to it below my `axios.get`, how to fix it?

---

**EDIT2**

Now as RoyJ recommended (probably because I shouldn't manipulate DOM as vue use its virtual DOM) in comment section I'm binding style by `:style` directive in template

```
        <div class="most__popular"
             v-for="n in articles" :key="n.id"
             :style="{margin: sliderMargin}">
```

so i set margin equal to sliderMargin variable which is changing in my function:

```
changeSlide() {
    setInterval(() => {
        switch (this.step) {
            case 1:
                console.log('step1');
                this.sliderMargin = '10px 0 0 0';
                this.step = 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                console.log('step2');
                this.sliderMargin = '-190px 0 0 0';
                this.step = 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                console.log('step3');
                this.sliderMargin = '-190px 0 0 0';
                this.step = 1;
                break;
        }
    },5000);
}
```

but it doesn't work as I want because it add margin to every element so in result it's not scroling but it's gone. So what I have to do is:

- on first step all elements have margin-top: 10px
- on second step 1,2,3 elements have margin-top: -190px and rest have 10px
- on third step 1,2,3,4,5,6 elements have margin-top: -190px rest have 10px

Question is how to adjust `:style` only for first three if `this.step` equal 2 or six if `this.step` equal 3 or to none if `this.step` equal 1?

Comment: Don't manipulate the DOM. Manipulate your viewmodel and let Vue reflect it in the DOM. See [Binding inline styles](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles)

Comment: So I've got to bind variable with styles and just change value in variable every 5 second right?

Comment: @RoyJ How I can bind styles with `:style` only for first 3 elements?

Comment: Update your question to show what code you have now and the HTML where the bindings are.

Comment: @RoyJ done, take a look at edit2 section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `setInterval`, you are not going to test `this.step`, you're just going to update its value. It uses modulo arithmetic to loop through values of 0, 1, 2.

You will make a computed that computes the margin for each article based on its index (0 - 5) and on the value of `this.step`. So `sliderMargin` is an array with one element for each element of `articles`. In the `v-for`, the element from `sliderMargin` that corresponds to the `article` is used.

`thresholds` indicates how many articles for a given step will have the 10px margin vs the -190px margin.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    articles: [1,2,3,4,5,6],
    step: 0
  },
  computed: {
    sliderMargin() {
      const thresholds = [0, 3, 6];

      return this.articles.map((_, i) =>
        `${(i < thresholds[this.step]) ? '10px' : '-190px'} 0 0 0`
      );
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.step = (this.step + 1) % 3;
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="most__popular" v-for="n, i in articles" :key="n.id" :style="{margin: sliderMargin[i]}">
    {{n}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is `0 0 0` in **sliderMargin** return ?

Comment: Just margin settings, as he did them in his question.

Comment: well i had to change `(i < thresholds[this.step])` to `(i > thresholds[this.step])` in order to make it working correctly, I dont realy understand what this code is doing but it's working.

Comment: @BT101 I've added a little more explanation of the code.

Comment: I encounter weird issue with your approach. When I see only bottom half or even less of my 580px height div where I animate those 3 boxes it's affecting my entire page scrolling it down. It probably have to do with this minus margin

Comment: Do you know what may be the reason of this scrolling behaviour?

Comment: It probably does have to do with the negative margins. You might want to try varying [scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) on the container rather than margins on the elements.